# Merge many DJVU files into one file

Tags: pdf, merge, djvu

I have a bunch of DJVU files (1.djvu, 2.djvu, etc). I want to merge these into one single file, either in DJVU format or PDF format. What is the best way of doing that? I am using Windows 7 and have Acrobat XI installed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some google search and found a free software which works really nicely. The name is DjvuToy and can be downloaded at [here](http://www.comicer.com/stronghorse/software/exe/DjVuToy_eng.zip).

You can just select the folder where all the djvu files are at and DjvuToy will merge them into a single DJVU file.

Answer (score 2):

```
djvm -c out.djvu 0.djvu 1.djvu 2.djvu...
```

Comment: Look [here](https://opensource.com/article/19/3/comic-book-archive-djvu) for an explanation.